# How can I calculate utilities for attribute levels in conjoint analysis in R?

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, logit, conjoint-analysis

I conducted a stated preference survey in which each respondent had to choose 1 set out of 3 choice sets (A, B and C), which are characterised by 4 attributes (let's say brand, color, size and keyboard yes/no) of either 2 or 3 levels.

I tried to calculate the utilities/coefficients with the estimation of multinomial logit model using the mlogit package in R. It's working well to calculate the utilities for the attributes (I followed exactly the script of Yves Croissant in his paper on the mlogit package.)

But I want to calculate the coefficients not for the attributes, but for the levels. I want to know what is the utility e.g. for the color "blue".
How can I calculate this? Is it possible at all to calculate it with the mlogit package or R?

I am grateful for every advice!

Answer (score 0):

Utility is an ordinal concept, so the utility of a particular level can only be interpreted relative to something else.  In your example, the utility of "blue" should be interpreted relative to, say, "red."

Since most of your attributes are categorical rather than continuous, you've probably used dummy or effects coding in your model (and if you haven't, you should).  If you've used dummy coding, the utility of each design-coded parameter can be interpreted relative to the excluded reference level.  For example, if you used "no keyboard" as the reference level for the keyboard attribute, the coefficient on the "with keyboard" parameter represents the incremental utility associated with adding a keyboard.  The same applies to the colour attribute: the coefficient on the different dummy-coded parameters represents the incremental utility of a particular colour relative to the excluded colour.

Note that the interpretation of the coefficients on dummy-coded (0,1) and effects-coded (-1,1) parameters are slightly different.  The coefficient on an effects coded parameter represents the deviation of the ‘level mean utility’ from ‘overall mean utility’, which not necessarily the same as the difference from the reference level as with a dummy-coded parameter.  Dummy-coded parameters are a little easier to interpret, but you run into problems with confounding between the utility of the reference levels and the alternative-specific constant (i.e. the intercept).  This is a particular problem if you're using a labelled design, but arguably less critical in a generic design.  See this reference for a useful summary... http://methodology.psu.edu/media/techreports/12-120.pdf.  There is also a good summary in [Hensher, Rose and Greene](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521605776).